# Angular 7/8 Custom Directive - I Cannot Detect Windows Scroll Events

Tags: angular

I am trying to learn how to handle events with some trouble on detecting window scroll.

The following is my scenario:

D:\wamp64\www\NGAPPS\logiico>ng version

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 7.3.9
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.15
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.9
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.9
@angular/cdk                      7.3.7
@angular/cli                      7.3.9
@angular/material                 7.3.7
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.9
@schematics/angular               7.3.9
@schematics/update                0.13.9
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.29.0
```

Then I have the following code snippet trying to learn how to detect elements that come into view port...

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.scroll = fromEvent(window, "scroll")
      .pipe(debounceTime(100))
      .subscribe(event => {
        this.logEvent();
      });

    this.resize = fromEvent(window, "resize")
      .pipe(debounceTime(100))
      .subscribe(event => {
        this.logEvent();
      });
  }
```

Whenever I resize my window, logEvent (a simple call to console.log()) is called as expected. Why doesn't 'scroll' work as expected when I scroll the window? There is no error, just silence...

Comment: Can you try to run only the scroll event ?

Comment: @TonyNgo there's no difference, 'scroll' doesn't seem to work

Comment: works fine here... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rn2638?file=src/app/app.component.ts